# Creating Ambient mode for Gear S2 watch face in Tizen SDK

Tags: sdk, tizen

I would like to enable ambient mode in my standalone watch face (.wgt format) that is written in Tizen SDK for Gear S2.
I constantly get an error message: "Attribute `ambient_support` is not allowed to appear in element `tizen:application`" when i place  ambient_support="enable" at the end of this line of code in config.xml:

What could be the reason for that?

Also, how do i connect the ambient mode feature to my ambient mode graphic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you build an app on tizen_2.3.1 wearable SDK?

Um... i don't get that kinda error msg when i made a ambient sample application.

I followed below step.

1, New->Tizen Native project->Templete->Watch Application.
2, Check whether Ambient support is checked of not.
   in project->tizen-manifest.xml->Advanced tap.

To check ambient_mode in emulator

1, Build and install your application, then chage default watch to yours.
(setting->clock)
2, you should turn on the display mode to Always on 
(setting->display->Check Always on)

Hope it helps.

Tested manifest file below.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://tizen.org/ns/packages" package="org.example.watch" api-version="2.3.1" version="1.0.0">
    <profile name="wearable" />
    <watch-application appid="org.example.watch" exec="watch" ambient-support="true">
        <icon>watch.png</icon>
        <label>watch</label>
    </watch-application>
    <privileges>
        <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm.set</privilege>
    </privileges>
</manifest>`

Comment: Thanks a lot Woochan! I'm using Tizen 2.3.1 wearable SDK. It seems that i don't have tizen-manifest.xml file in my watch face project. How can i include manifest file into my existing watch face?

Comment: manifest file will be created automatically when you make a tizen native project in SDK.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that. I have just one more thing to ask regarding ambient mode graphics. How can i connect the ambient mode to my ambient graphics (background image and hands images)?

Comment: there is a callback to notice ambient mode enabled.
"app_ambient_changed" please refer to ClassicWatch sample application in tizen_2.3.1 SDK... here is not good to attach code :(

Comment: Thanks Woochan! I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Ambient_Support was added in Tizen 2.3.1. Make sure your application use api-version (native) or required_version (web) with 2.3.1 or higher

Comment: Thanks Marco! Yes, i have Tizen 2.3.1, but it seems that when i made my watch face project i haven't included tizen.manifest.xml file. How can i include it in my existing watch face project? Also, do you know how could i connect my ambient graphics to ambient mode?

Comment: Tizen has two different application types... Native applications (.tpk) and Web applications (.wgt)... For both types u have two different .xml-files with enhanced information for ur application.

For web application you have to configure your application details by config.xml, native applications have the tizen-manifest.xml